# Design Pattern for dual purpose class (in-memory cache or table)

Tags: caching, design-patterns, decorator, strategy-pattern

I need to implement CRUD operations on a data source which could be a physical table or logic (in-memory cache holds data after query multiple tables). Ideal choice for data source is table in db. But due to some reasons there is alternate implementation of having in-memory cache class mimic ideal implementation.

```
interface IEmp
{
      Add();
      Update();
      Remove();
}
```

There are 2 implementation :

1. Class Emp

Operates on Physical table in sqlite

2. Class EmpCache

Operates in-memory cache - aggregate data from multiple other tables

Based on performance or other non functional needs consumer of class may chose to switch to either of 2 options.

I am thinking to apply design pattern here so that not causing much rework.

I see 2 design patterns applicable here:

**a. Strategy pattern** -

There will be 2 separate implementations of an interface IEmp (as above). 
e.g.

```
Class EmpTable
{
     IEmp table;
     bool isInMemory;
}
```

based on isInMemory T/F `table` will switch underlying instance to 1 of above implementation {`Emp` or `EmpCache`}

**b. Decorator pattern** - another interface extends + encapsulate IEmp interface. And based on property change - it will act / delegate as appropriate 
e.g.

```
IEmpCache : IEmp
{
     IEmp instance;
     bool useCache;
}
EmpCache : IEmpCache
{
     Add()
     {
         if(!useCache)
         {
             instance.Add();
         }
         //cache logic
     }
     ... // same for all other methods
}
```

I see approach **b** better, but mostly used when need to add/enhance already released functionality (class/interface), isn't it?

Which is better? Is there any other better pattern?

Comment: which one did you go with?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely choice B is better.

If we first take a look at how the following patterns are classified. A decorator is a structural pattern and strategy is a behavioral pattern.

> **[Decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator)** is a structural design pattern that lets you attach new behaviors to objects by placing these objects inside special wrapper objects that contain the behaviors.

Based on your question, you want to add new behavior to the existing object. Definition of the decorator is just like you describe your problem. Cache is the new behavior you want to add. I have used it in a similar problem and it usually works very well. It works well with a class that you can't change or with new features that could someday need caching.

> **[Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)** is a behavioral design pattern that lets you define a family of algorithms, put each of them into a separate class, and make their objects interchangeable.

I haven't used strategy to cache data. According to the definition, I think it has a different purpose. It can be harder to implement with already released classes. The strategy has many use cases and for example, it can be better when you do some calculations that may change.

I have used the strategy pattern when working with the database but it was a case where I wanted to support many different complex queries. In that way, I could just implement queries with strategy pattern and pass that strategy to object that handle database connection.